# Cannot install pyside6 python 3.9.0 32bit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6

The error message suggests that pip couldn't find a compatible version of PySide6 to install.

I wanna use 32bit python version!

`pip install PySide6`

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide6 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for PySide6

I attempted it in both Python 3.11 and 3.10, and I encountered the identical problem.

Comment: There are no 32bit binaries for Qt6, then, there are none for PySide too. If you want to use 32bit architecture with Qt6, you need to compile *both* Qt *and* PySide on your own.